# ImportError: No module named corsheaders

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-cors-headers

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'login.apps.LoginConfig',
    'mainsaaas.apps.MainsaaasConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

even i installed

pip install django-cors-headers. now it is shows import error for corsheaders and this the traceback i have checked virtual environment and corsheaders package is there

```
> Trace back:
>     
>     
>     Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f5a7d5a1aa0> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/next/virtual_env/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
> line 226, in wrapper
>         fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/next/virtual_env/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",
> line 113, in inner_run
>         autoreload.raise_last_exception()   File "/home/next/virtual_env/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
> line 249, in raise_last_exception
>         six.reraise(*_exception)   File "/home/next/virtual_env/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
> line 226, in wrapper
>         fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/next/virtual_env/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py",
> line 27, in setup
>         apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "/home/next/virtual_env/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
> line 85, in populate
>         app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)   File "/home/next/virtual_env/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py",
> line 90, in create
>         module = import_module(entry)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
>         __import__(name) ImportError: No module named corsheaders
```

Am using virtual environment and my django version is:  Django==1.10.5

Comment: which python version you are using and whether you are using virtual environment or not?

Comment: I think the 'django-cors-headers' works for Django versions : 1.8, 1.9, 1.10. Have you checked that?

Comment: what's your import error? Include the traceback.

Comment: you said your using virtual env. first login to you virtual env. then check pip freeze whether corsheader is listing or not

Answer (score 1):

CorsMiddleware should be placed as high as possible, especially before any middleware that can generate responses such as Django's CommonMiddleware or Whitenoise's WhiteNoiseMiddleware. If it is not before, it will not be able to add the CORS headers to these responses.

Also if you are using CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER it should be placed before Django's CsrfViewMiddleware

Answer (score 0):

you can try that command
`pip install django-cors-headers`
i use Django version:Django==2.1.7 ,python version:Python==3.6,
first i try `pip3 install django-cors-headers`,
the module name `corsheaders` could not found,
then i try 
`pip install django-cors-headers`
it worked
that may help you
consider about version of pip

Answer (score 0):

Just install from pip

```
python -m pip install django-cors-headers
```

And then add it to your installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]
```

Hopefully, it will work. If not working then restart your server and run again.